# Função na struct em C

Tags: c

Estou querendo transformar todo o processo de input e output da estrutura em funções, porém estou tendo problemas com o resultado que retorna, acredito ser algo pela função estar como void, testei outros tipos de dados mas ai nem sequer compila, conseguem me ajudar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct pc{
    char cpu[25];
    char gpu[25];
    int ram;
    int hd;
}Pc;


void ler(Pc entrada);
void resposta(Pc a);

int main (void){
    Pc entrada;
    Pc a;

    ler(entrada);
    resposta(a);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

void ler(Pc entrada){
    printf("CPU:");
    gets(entrada.cpu);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("GPU:");
    gets(entrada.gpu);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("RAM:");
    scanf("%i", &entrada.ram);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("HD:");
    scanf("%i", &entrada.hd);
    fflush(stdin);

}

void resposta(Pc a){
    printf("\nCPU:%s", a.cpu);
    printf("\nGPU:%s", a.gpu);
    printf("\nRAM:%iGB", a.ram);
    printf("\nHD:%iGB", a.hd);

}
```

Comment: Estude sobre ponteiros e utilize um ponteiro para a estrutura como parâmetro em sua função de leitura. Observe que, como em qualquer outra função em C, a passagem do parâmetro é feita por valor, isto significa que eventuais alterações na estrutura feitas dentro da função não terão efeito na variável fora da função.

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na função `ler()`, que recebe o parametro `entrada` por meio do seu valor, ou seja, quando ela é chamada, o parametro `entrada` é "copiado" para dentro do escopo da função e destruído imediatamente após o seu retorno.

Logo, a função `ler()` está modificando uma cópia, sem surtir efeito na estrutura passada.

Uma solução seria a passagem do parametro por ponteiro, veja só como seu código ficaria:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct pc{
    char cpu[25];
    char gpu[25];
    int ram;
    int hd;
}Pc;

void ler(Pc *entrada); //Passagem de parametro por "ponteiro"
void resposta(Pc a);

int main(void){
    Pc a;
    ler(&a); //Passagem de parametro (endereço de 'a')
    resposta(a);
    return 0;
}

void ler(Pc *entrada){ //Passagem de parametro por "ponteiro"
    printf("CPU: ");
    scanf("%s", entrada->cpu); //Acessando elemento 'cpu' atraves de um ponteiro
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("GPU: ");
    scanf("%s", entrada->gpu); //Acessando elemento 'gpu' atraves de um ponteiro
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("RAM: ");
    scanf("%d", &entrada->ram); //Acessando elemento 'ram' atraves de um ponteiro
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("HD: ");
    scanf("%d", &entrada->hd); //Acessando elemento 'hd' atraves de um ponteiro
    fflush(stdin);
}

void resposta(Pc a){
    printf("CPU: %s\n", a.cpu);
    printf("GPU: %s\n", a.gpu);
    printf("RAM: %d GB\n", a.ram);
    printf("HD: %d GB\n", a.hd);
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/StarchyDullFeed)